# mysqli_query failing with no error output in POST request

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post

I have a Database and I need to insert a row in it. I made a php file to be called remotely and insert the new row with POST parameters.

```
$res = mysqli_query($con,$consulta);
if($res == false) {
   echo(mysqli_error($con)." - ".$consulta);
}
```

It is intended to be called from an app, but for testing I made this simple html-JQuery

```
$.post('AMETarjetas.php', {'user_id':'1', 'digitos':'1111', 'marca':'MasterCard'}, function(data) {
      alert(data);
});
```

Nevermind the parameters, they are not the problem... As a result of creating the query I get:

```
INSERT INTO TARJETA (digitos, marca, user_id) VALUES ('1111','MasterCard','1');
```

So, the row was NOT inserted but when I copy&paste the same query in PhpMyAdmin it does work, and it does insert the new row in the database! Besides, the "mysqli_error($con)" is not printing anything, all I get is the query (above) :/

I have tried with different users but not even root works... A similar php file that makes a SELECT does work and fetches me data correctly.

Anything I could try? Thanks!

Comment: You got the ` - ` too?

Comment: Yeah, i just copied the query part into PhpMyAdmin to see if it worked... And it did, the alert printed "-..."

Comment: Perhaps turning on the MySQL query log will allow you to see what the db server is getting when the query is executed and you'll be able to confirm it's getting sent ok.